# Run computed function after mounted - VUE

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to run a function that needs some data that I get back from the mounted method. Right now I try to use `computed` to create the function but unfortunately for this situation computed runs before `mounted` so I don't have the data I need for the function. Here is what I'm working with:

```
    computed: {
      league_id () {
        return parseInt(this.$route.params.id)
      },
      current_user_has_team: function() {
        debugger;
      }
    },
    mounted () {
      const params = {};

      axios.get('/api/v1/leagues/' +this.$route.params.id, {
        params,
        headers: {
          Authorization: "Bearer "+localStorage.getItem('token')
        }
      }).then(response => {
        debugger;
        this.league = response.data.league
        this.current_user_teams = response.data.league
      }).catch(error => {
        this.$router.push('/not_found')
        this.$store.commit("FLASH_MESSAGE", {
          message: "League not found",
          show: true,
          styleClass: "error",
          timeOut: 4000
        })
      })
    }
```

As you can see I have the `debugger` in the computed function called `current_user_has_team` function. But I need the data I get back from the axios call. Right now I don't have the data in the debugger. What call back should I use so that I can leverage the data that comes back from the network request? Thank You!

Comment: Are you using `this.league` or `this. current_user_teams` inside  `current_user_has_team`? If yes, this computed property should be re-computed automatically when data come back from axios call

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If your computed property `current_user_has_team` depends on data which is not available until after the axios call, then you need to either:

1. In the `current_user_has_team` property, if the data is not available then return a sensible default value.
2. Do not access `current_user_has_team` from your template (restrict with `v-if`) or anywhere else until after the axios call has completed and the data is available.

It's up to you how you want the component to behave in "loading" situations.

Answer (score 5):

If your behavior is **synchronous**, you can use `beforeMount` instead of `mounted` to have the code run before computed properties are calculated.